# Сохранение введённых данных в текстовое поле

Tags: html

Есть код:

> `<input type="text" id="txt" value="">
> <input type="button" onclick="" id="b" value="Сохранить">`

Можно ли при нажатии на кнопку 'Сохранить' сохранять значение текстового поля? Допустим, я ввёл в текстовое поле текст "777", и мне нужно сохранить это не в отдельный файл, а в этот. 
И в итоге после сохранения должно получится это:

> `<input type="text" id="txt" value="777">
> <input type="button" onclick="" id="b" value="Сохранить">`

Как это можно сделать? )

Comment: Здравствуйте ) подскажите, а вы все-таки решили эту проблему? или это невозможно?
У меня просто сейчас ровно такая же задача стоит...

Comment: @flame я решил использовать бпзу данных MySQL. Сервер написал на языке PHP. Но я до сих пор не уверен, что это был лучший вариант, уже давно этим не занимался.

Comment: @flame, смотря для чего Вам это нужно. Если, например, необходимо реализовать чат или форум, то там есть важные моменты, а если просто какие-то небольшие данные, то можно использовать JSON. Вы лучше скажите, для чего конкретно. Можете отдельный вопрос задать, если хотите.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе сначала нужно определиться, куда сохранять, потому что можно сохранить как в текстовый файл и потом его открывать и присваивать полю через переменную значение, что очень муторно и неудобно, либо через базу данных, но там своя история...

Comment: Все действия должны происходить в одном файле. Вот так это должно быть: Открыл файл / Изменил значение текстового поля / Нажал на кнопку / Сохранились изменения (в этом же файле). И в итоге, после следующего открытия этого файла, то должно быть присвоено то значение, которое я вводил в текстовое поле.